# Assign number from a range to values but do not re-use a number from the given range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem where it requires the assignment of a new number based on a given range.   Whatever number from the given range is assigned cannot be re-used.

For example:

```
DOCNUM         Version

544124          1
124334          1
441204          1
```

Range given (2145777 - 3145777)

Basically the above three DOCNUMs would be assigned a new number based on the range, and the result would be:

```
DOCNUM       Version

2145777       1
2145778       1
2145779       1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select t.*,
       2145777 - 1 + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as new_docnum
from t;
```

Note:  This does NOT guarantee any sort of ordering -- just that the resulting values start with the value you want.  You might want to replace the `order by` if ordering is important.

You can put this in an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             2145777 - 1 + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as new_docnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set docnum = new_docnum;
```

Comment: I think that best practices here is to create a new field (old_docnum) and save the original value -- you can delete the column later but this allows you to test and make sure you did actually get expected results.